# How can I tell if berkshelf is connecting to my chef server

Tags: chef-infra, knife, berkshelf

I am attempting to use berkshelf with chef to provision a Vagrant machine. This is running on Windows 7. I installed Berkshelf as part of the Chef-DK. It reports version 3.2.3. My vagrant provisioning was failing because it cannot find some cookbooks. Here is the relevant bit of my Berksfile

```
source "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/createthegood"
#source "https://api.berkshelf.com"

metadata

cookbook "drupal_site"
cookbook "al_base"
```

When I run a berks install, it fails to index the source:

```
D:\Rob\VMs\ctg_cookbook>berks install
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching 'artifact' from git://github.com/RiotGames/artifact-cookbook.git (at master)
Fetching 'ctg_cookbook' from source at .
Fetching 'drush' from git://github.com/jenkinslaw/chef-drush.git (at 0a567e2)
Fetching 'php-fpm' from git://github.com/yevgenko/cookbook-php-fpm.git (at master)
Fetching cookbook index from https://api.opscode.com/organizations/createthegood...
D:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/berkshelf-api-client-1.2.1/lib/berkshelf/api
_client/connection.rb:67:in `block in universe': undefined method `each' for #<String:0x3fdc4e8>
 (NoMethodError)
        from D:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/berkshelf-api-client-1.2.1/lib/
berkshelf/api_client/connection.rb:66:in `tap'
        from D:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/berkshelf-api-client-1.2.1/lib/
berkshelf/api_client/connection.rb:66:in `universe'
        from D:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/berkshelf/lib/berkshelf/source.rb:22:in `build_univ
erse'
        from D:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/berkshelf/lib/berkshelf/installer.rb:21:in `block (
2 levels) in build_universe'
```

However, knife finds that cookbook on its configured server:

```
C:\Users\29007>knife cookbook list help
7-zip                  1.0.2
activelamp_composer    0.0.1
activelamp_drupal      0.0.4
activelamp_symfony     0.0.1
al_base                0.0.1
```

I thought that perhaps it berkshelf wasn't picking up on the configuration info from knife (like the keyfiles, perhaps). But I can't seem to come up with a way to verify that. What's my next step in trying to diagnose this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe Hosted Chef provides a Berkshelf API that you can use inside your Berksfile. Berkshelf needs to talk to a [berkshelf-api](https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf-api), which indexes all your Chef Server's cookbooks and then is able to do dependency resolution. This is why the `block in universe` fails because there's a `/universe` API resource in the berkshelf-api. It looks like Hosted Chef doesn't support it.

Normally in your Berksfile you put your internal berkshelf-api first and put the community berkshelf-api second. In this case, the community api is now at https://supermarket.chef.io. If your cookbooks only depend on cookbooks available on Supermarket, you won't have to set up your own Berkshelf API.

If you do plan on writing cookbooks that depend on your own cookbooks, the best approach would be to set up a [berkshelf-api](https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf-api) server. There's a [cookbook](https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf-api/tree/master/cookbook) and you can set it up and point it at your [Hosted Chef organization](https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf-api#chef-server). You could also set up [your own supermarket](https://github.com/chef/supermarket/wiki/Deployment) which also provides a Berkshelf API.

Comment: Interesting. That seems like kind of a pain for the specific environment I have. Would it be possible instead to use knife to pre-download the cookbooks into my shelf? Or should I look at something like putting those specific cookbooks in a git repo and referencing them by URL?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the berkshelf-api hasn't been integrated into the chef server. I think given Chef DK ships with Berkshelf, I hope Chef is standardizing on it (there are others like Librarian Chef). I think the Git approach will work best. If the cookbooks you have are open source you could also upload them to [supermarket](https://supermarket.chef.io/). It's also possible to run [your own supermarket](https://github.com/chef/supermarket/wiki/Deployment).

Comment: I've updated my answer, basically if you only depend on cookbooks available on supermarket you don't need to set anything up.

Comment: What I've ended up doing is using knife to download them to a local directory and hardcoding the path in the Berksfile. I'm running into a different problem at the moment that is keeping me from getting all the way to success. Once I knock that out and am sure that I have a working path forward, I'll come back and accept your answer. Actually, what I think I will end up doing is downloading those cookbooks into the source repo of the project and updating the Berksfile to refer to the path in the project. Tight coupling, but at least it will always provision.

Comment: @rhuffstedtler are the cookbooks you depend on in Supermarket or are they your own cookbooks?